# How to add spannablestring to a list in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to add spannablestring to list in android.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(jObject.getString("Categories")); 
List<String> uNumList = new ArrayList<String>();
uNumList.add(ss);
```

Comment: What, precisely, is `uNumList`? What, specifically, is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: List<String> uNumList = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpannableString` does not extend `String`. Both `String` and `SpannableString` extend `CharSequence`.

Hence, you can make `uNumList` be either `List<SpannableString>` (if all entries will be `SpannableString` instances) or `List<CharSequence>` (if it will hold a mix of `String` and `SpannableString` instances).

Comment: But the text and image is getting wrapped in string